# Disable browser links in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to disable the links ( `<a ... >` elements ) in the browser in Windows Phone 8? I would like to display a page from which the user cannot navigate to another page and I don't have control over the source code of the page that I am showing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribe to WebBrowser's [`Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event and cancel all navigation attempts by setting `Cancel` property of [`NavigatingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.navigatingeventargs%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to true.